# Weird behavior with web2py DAL on table definition

Tags: database, web2py

Hi getting behaviour I don't understand with web2py

```
In [50]: db = DAL('sqlite://deposit/sample.sqlite')

In [51]: db.define_table('customer',Field('name','string',required=True),
     Field('nric','string',required=True),
     Field('address','string'),
     Field('phone','integer'),
     primarykey=['name'])
Out[51]: <Table customer (name,nric,address,phone)>
```

works as expected.

I then do

```
In [53]: db.define_table('check',
         Field('nric', db.customer.nric, required=True), 
         Field('clear','string'))
```

which gets me the message

```
AttributeError: 'DAL' object has no attribute 'customer.nric'
```

So thinking this may be an issue of not having committed `customer` to the database

so I do a `db.commit()` and then try again

```
In [56]: db.define_table('check',Field('nric', db.customer.nric, required=True), Field('clear','string'))
  File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: table already defined: check
```

Not sure why .. but anyway I try and drop the table

```
In [59]: db['check'].drop()
```

and get the following weird traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-998297b798f5> in <module>()
----> 1 db['check'].drop()

/home/tahnoon/.dropbox-cyn/Dropbox (TIS Group)/Cynopsis/Builds/Apollo/Code Src/web2py/gluon/dal.pyc in drop(self, mode)
   9225 
   9226     def drop(self, mode=''):
-> 9227         return self._db._adapter.drop(self, mode)
   9228 
   9229     def _listify(self, fields, update=False):

/home/tahnoon/.dropbox-cyn/Dropbox (TIS Group)/Cynopsis/Builds/Apollo/Code Src/web2py/gluon/dal.pyc in drop(self, table, mode)
   1328         queries = self._drop(table, mode)
   1329         for query in queries:
-> 1330             if table._dbt:
   1331                 self.log(query + '\n', table)
   1332             self.execute(query)

/home/tahnoon/.dropbox-cyn/Dropbox (TIS Group)/Cynopsis/Builds/Apollo/Code Src/web2py/gluon/dal.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   9108             return self._db(self._id == key).select(limitby=(0, 1), orderby_on_limitby=False).first()
   9109         elif key:
-> 9110             return ogetattr(self, str(key))
   9111 
   9112     def __call__(self, key=DEFAULT, **kwargs):

AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute '_dbt'
```

Checking tables shows

```
In [61]: db.tables()
Out[61]: ['customer']
```

Is this expected behaviour? If so how do I drop/create a table after a syntax error? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `db.customer` is a keyed table (i.e., you have defined a `primarykey` attribute rather than relying on the default autoincrement integer ID field as the primary key), it can only be referenced by other keyed tables.

Also, when creating reference fields for keyed tables, use the following syntax:

```
Field('nric', 'reference customer.nric', required=True)
```

However, I don't think keyed tables are supported for SQLite (the docs say only DB2, MS-SQL, Ingres, and Informix are supported). Anyway, if you are creating a new table in SQLite, there is no reason to use a keyed table (that functionality was added primarily to enable access to legacy databases that lack autoincrement integer primary key fields).

Finally, dropping a table does not remove the model from the `db` DAL instance -- rather, that operation drops the table from the database itself. If you want to redefine a model within a shell session, you should use the "redefine" argument:

```
db.define_table(..., redefine=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. That's exactl what I needed. A quick follow up, what if the field has a different name in the second table, is that possible? And if so, how do I let web2py know which fields to reference?

Comment: Sorry, made some corrections to the answer. With keyed tables, you do specify the table and field name, as now shown above. However, I don't think keyed tables are fully supported on SQLite, so you may get some errors.